# Volley: make request with List<T> in JSONObject

Tags: android, android-volley, json

I use `Volley` and need send to server list of objects `User` and `List<Integer>`.

`User` class:

```
public class User {

        public int id;
        public String name;

        public MyClass(int id, String name){
            this.id = id;
            this.name= name;
        }
}
```

I use code

```
    HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();

    List<Integer> categories = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(5, 8, 9));
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            new User(1, "User1"),
            new User(2, "User2"),
            new User(3, "User3")
    ));


    params.put("categories", categories);
    params.put("users", users);

    JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject(params);
```

The problem is JSONObject can't parse `User`

```
{
    "users": [
        null,
        null,
        null
    ],
    "categories": [
        5,
        8,
        9
    ]
}
```

How to parse it with `JSONObject`?

Parameter "`users`" should be `array` not `string`.

I need `JSONObject` because `Volley` use it

```
JsonObjectRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
            Listener<JSONObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener)
```

[image]

Full code:

```
package com.example.admin.testjson;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();

        List<Integer> categories = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(5, 8, 9));
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                new User(1, "User1"),
                new User(2, "User2"),
                new User(3, "User3")
        ));


        params.put("categories", categories);
        params.put("users", users);

        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject(params);


    }
}


package com.example.admin.testjson;


    public class User {
        int id;
        String name;

        public User(int id, String name){
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which JSON framework do you use?

Comment: In the project I use Jackson, Volley use org.json

Answer (score 1):

I think you should replace `MyClass` by `User` in **User** class like this

```
public class User {

    public int id;
    public String name;

    public User(int id, String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name= name;
    }
}
```

I have tested building JSONObject with your code, the **users** not null!

[image]

UPDATE:

Try use my following code for your new blank project (my project runs normally, users not null):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();

    List<Integer> categories = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(5, 8, 9));
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            new User(1, "User1"),
            new User(2, "User2"),
            new User(3, "User3")
    ));


    params.put("categories", categories);
    params.put("users", users);

    JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject(params);
    Log.i("BNK", jsonBody.toString());
}

public class User {

    public int id;
    public String name;

    public User(int id, String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name= name;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, for tried run the code. MyClass is just a typo in my sample, use right constructor. And in the screenshot "users" is  String is json, not array. Is strangely I tried run code and give null, please see my update.

Comment: Where did you define your User class? Try create a new `User.java` file and define this class. Then, re-run the app

Comment: Moreover, try remove Jackson temporarily, just use default JSON

Comment: User class define in User.java file. Ok, I will try create new project, without Jackson.

Comment: Blank project without dependencies not helped, mystic

Comment: Can you post your full code of MainActivity.java and User.java (your new blank project)?

Comment: Try using my new updated code for your new blank project. I have just created a new project and it works normally (users not null)

Comment: If you have tried with my new code and your issue still not solved, I think you should check your environment more (such as compileSdkVersion, my project uses `compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"`).

Comment: thank you for the help, I think problem in environment, no more suggestions

Comment: Have you found a working solution for this issue yet?